# How would I use WASD and the Enter key to select an image in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Trying to create a card matching game in javascript for school, and I can't seem to figure out how to use my WASD selector (which is currently just a red card outline overlayed on top of the card back), and Enter to select the card that the selector is hovering over. The cards and selector are arranged on a grid right now, with the card face images on the bottom layer, then the card backs, and then the selector. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.